# Create function which selects columns using column name and a prefix in r

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I want to create a function that selects two columns, a column based on the input to the function and a second column that has a prefix of "other_" to the first column thats being selected (in the example that is "Species" and "other_Species". Without adding another input to the function.

```
library(tidyverse)
iris_df <- iris %>%
  mutate(other_Species = Species)

iris_fn <- function (df, col){
df%>%
select(all_of(col, paste0("other_",col)))
}

iris_fn(df=iris_df, col="Species")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform `"other_Species"` in a symbol first. And `all_of` accepts only one argument at a time.
Another option, like it is said in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77879906/create-function-which-selects-columns-using-column-name-and-a-prefix-in-r/77879958?noredirect=1#comment137297270_77879958), is to combine both character vectors with `c()`.

> What do you mean by `all_of()` only accepts one string at a time? It takes a character vector so you can use `select(all_of(c(col, paste0("other_", col))))` in the function, no need to convert to a symbol if you're passing a string.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(tidyverse)
)
iris_df <- iris %>%
  mutate(other_Species = Species)

iris_fn <- function (df, col){
  other_col <- sym(paste0("other_", col))
  df%>%
    select(all_of(col), all_of(other_col))
}

iris_fn(df = iris_df, col = "Species") %>% head()
#>   Species other_Species
#> 1  setosa        setosa
#> 2  setosa        setosa
#> 3  setosa        setosa
#> 4  setosa        setosa
#> 5  setosa        setosa
#> 6  setosa        setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @lotus OK, poorly explained. I should have said only *one argument*. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can take the advantage of `matches` in `select`.

```r
iris_df <- iris %>%
  mutate(other_Species = Species, 
         other_Speciesssss = Species) # dummy other_Speciesssss column for testing

iris_fn <- function (df, col){
  df%>%
    select(col, matches(paste0("^other_", col, "$")))
}

iris_fn(df=iris_df, col="Species")
```

Output

```r
# the dummy other_Speciesssss column was not selected 
       Species other_Species
1       setosa        setosa
2       setosa        setosa
3       setosa        setosa
```